# Azure Kubernetes Service pods not starting health check is timing out and no error logs

Tags: azure-aks

I am using Azure Kuerbets Services and Im having a huge problem to detect why pods (of specific type) isnt starting... The only thing that happens is that when new pods starts health check is timing out and silently AKS go back to old deployed services that worked... I have made a lot of trace output in service to detect where it fails if its external calls that are blocked etc and I have  a global try/catch in Program.cs but no information comes out... AKS listen on stdout and grabbing logs there and push them to external tool.... I have tried to increase values when health check should start etc as below but with no result

```
 livenessProbe:
         .
         .
         initialDelaySeconds: 60
         periodSeconds: 10
 readinessProbe:
          .
          .
          initialDelaySeconds: 50
          periodSeconds: 15
```

When running service locally its up in 10-15 sec

Obviously things seems to fail before service is started or something is timing out and I'm wondering...

1. Can I fetch logs or monitor whats happening and why pods are so slow in AKS when pods are starting?
2. Is it possible to monitor what comes out on stdout on an virtual machine that belongs to AKS-cluster?

Feels like I have tested everything but I cant find any reason why health-monitoring is refusing requests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled Azure Monitor for Container when you created your cluster, the logs of your application will be pushed to a Log Analytics workspace in the table `ContainerLog`. If Azure Monitor is not enable, you can use `kubectl` to see what is output to `stdout` and `sdterr` with the following command :

```
kubectl logs {pod-name} -n {namespace}
```

You can also check the kubernetes events, you'll see events saying that the probes failed If this is really the problem :

```
kubectl get events -n {namespace}
```